# 403 Access denied for DELETE Request .Net Web Api Rest Service on Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

I'm quite unsure of the reason for this. 
On localhost all request types work.

But when I publish to a Windows Azure Shared Site
GET, POST & PUT requests work and DELETE requests Fail.

Right after creating the Data I cannot delete it, this happens over my local ISP and works from my cell phones internet.

I've tried

1. ipconfig /flushdns
2. Changing to Google and OpenDNS
3. Adding a default document in web.config for Mvc - Views/Home/Index.cshtml
4. Adding - runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

This is all I get back.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Access Denied
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 16:15:44 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 249
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to enable the DELETE verb in your web.config.

(source: http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#enable-http-verbs)

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*."
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My initial one was the same with verb="*", I tried your idea as well, didnt work. It seems to be an issue with the DNS if DELETE requests can work on other ISPs but not mine.

Comment: Have you tried to connect your PC to internet using one of the working phones as a Wifi hotspot? In this way you can guess if the problme is you ISP or is some configuration on your PC.

Comment: wait, so you're saying that it's just your PC that the DELETE request doesn't work from?? Do you have a proxy configured? maybe Fiddler? it's hard to think that the DNS or ISP would affect http traffic as most of these operate at lower levels in the stack. an http proxy on the otherhand my do that.

Comment: When I use the phones Wifi hotspot it works. When I use the ISPs broadband it dosent. Only the Http DELETE request. Dns flush complete - no change. Very strange.